# Hair style software in 3D or with side hair design

Tags: photography, modeling, 3d

I have searched and found some software to design hair styles. But, they just over a hair image on one's front photos.

I am looking for a 3D hair style software, or one I can also design my side hair. I might choose a ready head model, or I might need to input many photos of me from different angles, and the software subsequently created the 3D model of my head. Or, simply overlapping a hair image at my side photo works for me too.

Prefer Windows or iOS.